# Does My Neighbor Sniff My Mobile Data Through Wifi

Tags: android

i am using an Android phone which is connected to my home Wifi Device(Tp Link) DSL Connection.
Can my neighbour hack my mobile and monitor my mobile traffic through software like WireShark, etc.?

Comment: You should include what kind of security your connection has, if not there's not much to answer.

Comment: Not if you have secured your WiFi using WPA2 with a strong passphrase. But if it is unsecured or secured with WEP, then yes.

Comment: Broad question - broad answer. Yes your neighbor can hack your network/phone and once done can monitor traffic to/from your phone. And in response to the comment on your question about WPA2... incorrect, WPA2 is not invincible.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps we can generalize things a little. Any wifi connection can potentially be breached and the attacker could use the "evil twin" attack so that you send all your wifi traffic to them, and they can use WireShark to collect your packets. This is true of any wifi connection and any wifi device.

There are ways to reduce the risk and to protect yourself, and those protections depend on the wifi equipment involved and your technical skill.

On the other hand, one cannot "hack your wifi" and gain access to the data sent over the cellular network, if that was what you were asking.

Comment: Doesn't the feasibility of an evil twin attack still ultimately depend on the security of the encryption used?

Comment: @user54791 i disagree. Evil Twin Attack is about creating an evil twin, turning the actual router down by attacking it and having the victim connect to the evil twin. So, i dont think the encryption used for the original router matters.

Comment: @Aatif But the victim will fail to connect to the evil twin if it is set up with the wrong encryption key, and it is not possible to extract the original key from the failed connection attempts...

Comment: @user54791 You could set up the evil twin with no encryption i.e open, that will automatically connect the victim to the evil twin.

Comment: @Aatif In my experience devices will not autoconnect to a network if the security type changes from what it was originally, for this exact reason. Windows displays a big red X on the network and will not allow you to connect unless you manually delete the original network profile, and OSX shows a warning message that the network security type has changed. I assume smartphones do something similar.

Comment: @user54791 See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evil_twin_%28wireless_networks%29
I haven't played around with Wireless security since a couple of years, at the time, when i used to perform the attack i described, my iOS devices used to connect automatically. We might need a third opinion on this as i am not aware how devices react nowadays.